# file_put_contents permission denied causing error writing to file

Tags: php

I have a text file with chmod 777 in some directory: /a/b/example.txt

I have a php script in another directory: /c/d/script.php

Calling file_put_contents in the php script gives a permission error. The file, example.txt has chmod 777 and all its parent directories have 700 or 775. I believe executable permissions should be enough for the parents.

HTML:

```
    <form method="POST">Add:<br>
        <input type="text" name="newEx"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

PHP:

    <?php
    // Add NS to example.txt

    if(isset($_POST['newEx'])) {
        $newEx = $_POST['newEx']."\n";
        $ret = file_put_contents('/home/a/b/example.txt', $newEx, FILE_APPEND  | LOCK_EX);
        if ($ret === false) {
            die('Error writing to example.txt');
        } else {
            echo "$ret written to file";
        }

    }

    ?>
```

This is the error message I get:

> Warning: file_put_contents(/home/a/b/example.txt): failed to open
>   stream: Permission denied in /home/c/d/script.php on line 103 Error
>   writing to example.txt

I have looked around but haven't found a working solution. Hoping for some further suggestions of things to try.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: If you're running on Apache with vhosts, you have to grant the vhost access to that directory on top of file and folder permissions.

Comment: @Enstage there's no code here, he's getting permission denied

Comment: He can't be generating a PHP error without code.

Comment: The problem is with directory permissions not the code

Comment: you're looking for chown here - my bet is Apache doesn't have write permissions because it's not in the right user group.

Comment: Just added an edit with the code of how this is being called. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Okay, so I now understand that it has to do with Apache user group, but I don't want to to change the APACHE_RUN_USER because there are multiple websites using this and I don't know the consequences of changing it for the others. Is there a way to set the user group for just a single website?

Comment: @Mr.Kaplan yeah, run the chown command on the webroot that belongs to you, e.g. chown -R apache_user_name:whatever_group www/ and that will apply it to only the www directory (recursively)